# Edit styleUrl of point KML file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml, style, maps.me

I have exported a file from Maps.me as a KML and want to edit the style in QGIS and then export it back to Maps.me.

It is possible to edit the styleUrl in the raw KML-file, then save the changes and import it into Maps.me, but there is no option to edit the styleUrl in QGIS.

In QGIS the styleUrl field does not appear when the KML is loaded into QGIS. I was wondering if it is at all possible to edit the styleUrl in QGIS?